# Trouble with Drop-down Menu on the Top Link Bar in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, navigation, global-navigation

I'm using SharePoint 2013 with full permissions. I've done a ton of research regarding this problem and still have yet to find a solution.

The template that is being used does not support the 'edit links' in top navigation. I do not have the power to change the template as this project is already past the point of an option like that.

While doing research on this problem I stumbled upon a video which showed a user going through the navigation setting and creating the drop-down menu by adjusting the location of links in the 'Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting'. This would work for me (I believe) BUT in the 'Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting' there are no labels indicating global navigation from current navigation. So I'm left with one very long drop-down menu with everything in it that is not in a heading. Each creation of a new heading goes straight to the current navigation.

Can anyone help with this problem?

- I've attached a copy of my navigation and the navigation that I'm looking for (notice the global and local navigation headers)

[image: Screenshot of my navigation]

[image: Navigation that I'm looking for]

Comment: What level of permissions do you have on this site?

Comment: I have full permissions

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62471)